# No matplotlib figure in interactive mode

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've ran into this weird problem with Matplotlib (1.5.1) / Python (3.5.2) on my new Macbook (El Capitan), where figures won't show in interactive mode. The `matplotlibrc` file is empty, except for the specification of `backend : macosx`.

If I create a `figure` inside `ipython` as:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
pl.figure()
pl.plot([0,1],[0,1])
pl.show()
```

The figure shows; however with:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
pl.ion() # or specifying `interactive : True` in my matplotlibrc file
pl.figure()
pl.plot([0,1],[0,1])
```

I get no figure (no plot window, nothing!), also not with `pl.show()`. With the `TkAgg` backend I get a slightly different behaviour: the first example again shows the figure, the second example shows the figure window, without any content (the `pl.plot()` part), stuck on the *spinning beach ball of death*.

Does anyone have any idea why/where this might be going wrong? On another system (Yosemite, Python 3.4.4, matplotlib 1.10.4) everything works as expected.

Comment: It seems to be related the ipython version I was using (ipython 5.0.0); downgraded to 4.2 (`pip uninstall ipython; pip install -Iv ipython==4.2`) it all works again.

Comment: There is an issue already open on the IPython GitHub repo (https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/9811). It appears that using the `%matplotlib` magic function works, rather than downgrading the IPython version. Figures are much slower to close for me than they have been in the past, but otherwise it seems to be OK.

Comment: Great, that indeed works with `ipython 5.0.0`